# How can I use Surefire to run parameterized tests in parallel?

Tags: selenium, junit

I am using jUnit's Parameterized annotation on some Selenium tests to specify the browsers they should run with. I am also using SureFire's new parallel parameter (set to "classes") to try and run them in parallel. Am I correct in assuming that if I have X test classes and Y browsers, I should see X*Y windows pop up, X of each type? I'm only seeing Y windows pop up at a time.

For example, let's say I have my parameter list set to Firefox and Chrome, and I have 10 test classes. When I execute the tests with Maven, I'm seeing one Firefox window and one Chrome window appear on my remote server at a time. I want to see 10 of each, one for each class, so it takes less time to run. Is this possible?

Comment: You have to create a own Parameterized class like here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504796/running-junit-parameterized-tests-in-parallel-in-eclipse

But be careful. I used this too and had some troubles with the number of parallel tests. Therefor this is not a answer. I think it is not the best way. But I have no other idea.

Comment: @Twaldigas I was using something like that (actually the one provided by Sauce Labs), but it only does one thread per browser. I want one per class, which Surefire supports.

Comment: Hmm... okay. When it not work create a issue at the JUnit project. Ask for a solution of your problem. The people are very cooperative. https://github.com/junit-team/junit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario works with maven-surefire-plugin 2.16 or higher, JUnit 4.7 or higher.
The Parameterized runner is a suite and therefore every single configuration means a new class. In your configuration of maven-surefire-plugin you should use parallel=classes and certain threadCount. You have many possibilities like classesAndMethods or threadCount + threadCountClasses, etc.
Just see the plugin documentation
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html